# writing a react based chat application with realtime updates Express, Mongodb, Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm writing an application for a chat application that will need to use `websockets` or `socket.io` to be checking for updates in the server. It will relay the information to all of the clients. The GitHub repository is connected.

I'm trying to figure out how to implement websockets/socket.io.
If anyone can give me some tips on placement of the files or help me figure it out that would be fantastic.

Link to the project: https://github.com/vschool-september-2017/chatter

Comment: check out The net ninja tutorials on YouTube.
He'll get you started on websockets with node.js . I learned from his tutorials